# jQuery Mobile- toggle collapsible listview

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, toggle

I have to toggle a collapsible listview when the user click on the `<h3>Yourself<h3>`.
The content inside the  Yourself supposed to be next (inline) the `<label class="text-light">Post as:</label>`

```
function changeHeader(event){
            var element = $(event.srcElement);
            $('#listHeader a').text("Post as: " + event.srcElement.innerHTML);
            $('#postAs').val($(event.srcElement).attr('data-postas'));
            if(element.attr('data-company')){
                    $('#company').val(element.attr('data-company'));

    }

    <fieldset >
                    <div>
                    <label class="text-light">Post as:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="collapsible"  data-collapsed-icon="carat-d" data-expanded-icon="carat-u" data-iconpos="right">
                        <h3 id="listHeader">Yourself</h3>
                        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false" onclick="changeHeader(event);" style="width: 125%">
                            <li data-postas="0">Yourself</li>
                            <g:if test="${companyList?.size() > 1}">
                                <li disabled="disabled" style="background-color: #CCCCCC">As your company</li>
                                <g:each var="company" in="${companyList}">
                                    <li data-postas="1" value="${company?.id}"   id="${company?.companyname}" data-company="${company?.id}">${company?.companyname}</li>
                                </g:each>
                             </g:if>
                            <g:else>
                                <input type="hidden" value="${companyList[0].id}" name="company"/>
                            </g:else>

                        </ul>
                        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: What is the question?  If you have attempted this, what was wrong with that attempt?

Comment: now it's a collapsible list view. The "head" of the list which indicates the selected item is the first line of the list view. I have to display it in the line of the <label class="text-light">Post as:</label>